# Поиск адресов электронной почты в большом слитном тексте

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите каким образом можно найти все майлы в большом текстовом файле на php?

Comment: в слитном,без пробелов тексте это нереально. С пробелами - гуглите "парсинг email php"

Comment: можно начать с http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения. Например, так

```
preg_match_all('/[^\s]+@\w+\.\w{1,4}/i', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```